# Make Color Custom Hoodies

Tags: clothing

I would like to make hoodies with gradient color for my team, but I can't find any store that suggests that, all that is suggested is a uni-color hoodies which I can print on.

Is there any company/shop that provides that service?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Meddah, Welcome to Lifehacks. What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, I updated my post, Im looking for a company that provides that service

Answer (score 1):

**More Screen-Time Lifehack:**

Contact any printing company that does SILK SCREEN PRINTING on clothing.
There are many different suppliers who do this work. Promotional advertising companies can also give you many references for suppliers.

Ask for a gradient screen pattern to be printed on your supply of hoodies.
 You will specify the percentage range of the gradient - from examples - and the hue that will be used for the gradient. A colour swatch book will be used for you to choose the colour.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**Colourful Lifehack:**
One way to get what you want is to make them yourself.

From personal experience, I found that nothing is impossible if you can get someone else to do it.

1. Find someone who will/or can custom-dye clothing
2. Make a deal
3. Try one for approval
4. Order a shipment of uni-colour hoodies (white)
5. Pick-up your order of unique team hoodies
6. Pay them
7. Take a bow

Good luck.

Shower Thought— Conventionally, a team has an identity colour. Our/(my) high school had purple (ugh) and white. There was even a song (also horrible) that featured the colour combo. What would you call the team colours when you have a gradient?
Fade to … white/black.